# CORDA-4.9.5-COLLABORATIVE-RECOVERY : Unable to recover data

Tags: corda, disaster-recovery, corda-flow

the steps we have tried are listed below,

-Enabled drain mode in nodes
-Installed collaborative recovery binaries in all nodes 
-On runnning flow list all the flows were listed
-Backup was created for the database.
-Simulated disaster by droping the database of PartyB(Note: There were transactions from PartyA -> PartyB)
-Initiated the reconcilation flow from PartyB(No differences found)

The same was done without backup and recovery
-PartyB database was dropped.
-Intitated reconcilation flow which showed the status DIFFERENCES_FOUND.The transaction id's of the missed transactions were also listed inside lastSuccessfulReconcilationResult.
-AutoRecoveryFlow showed status : failure, the error shown was that the autorecovery flow does is not supported when the transactions are beyond a certain limit.
-Manual recovery status showed done but the data was found to be still missing.

I did all the necessary steps as mentioned in corda docs, Even on dropping tables no differences were recovered.